# How to inject EJB into a Spring

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I have a stateless Bean with following heirarchy and present 
`accountserver` , `accountserverBean implements accountserver`.
 with there corresponding `ejb-jar.xml` and `weblogicjar.xml`

Then I have my spring Bean with the following
`payload.java` with corressponding `spring.xml`

So Inside the spring libs folder I have added `account.jar`

So how can I call method present in accountserverBean from payload class????

Also I have used the below Code in payload.java

```
Context ctx=new InitialContext();
accountserver as=(accountserver)ctx.lookup("java:com/accountserver");
```

But this doesnt work.

Since both are in same context I can call the EJB method
Please provide me with solution

Comment: Is everything part of one application? "Doesn't work" means exactly what? "Both are in the same context" - what context do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to integrate EJB and Spring applications. Did you try this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html  ?